# 7zip extract only if password protected

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I have an application that runs this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe x myArch.zip -aoa -ppassword -odestinationFolder
```

I want to make sure the application extracts only zip or 7z files that are password protected and were created by me.
Unfortunately, this command extracts archives that have no password, so anyone can extract an archive with my application.
How can I prevent that?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798671/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-is-password-protected-via-7zip) on SO seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Does the job. Thank you MMM :)